# .txt is added to my .apk when I email it out

Tags: android, apk

I am trying to help a client of mine install a .apk file on his phone. The issue is that we are in different states so I cannot physically see the phone. Whenever I email him a .apk file, his phone adds .txt to the name. So MyApplication.apk becomes MyApplication.apk.txt and he is unable to install it. I've told him to remove the .txt but he says this hasn't worked. Any ideas on how to install this on his phone?

My only guess right now is that his phone may not be enabled for .apk files which aren't from Google Play. Otherwise I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: I'm sending it over GMail, and now I'm trying to send it over Google Drive too.

Comment: Weird. Even if you're phone is not enabled to install APK's not from the Google Play store it should not add a .txt. In my personal experience it just gives a system message that you have not enabled the ability to install other APKs.

Comment: Are you both using GMail, or are they using a different email client? If yes, then my guess is that client is altering the file for "safety". Google Drive would be a great alternative in that case.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround could be to upload the file to Dropbox and give the client the public URL for the file. I'm not certain, but I think some filetypes are triggered in either yours or your clients email clients as a sort of "virus" protection.

If you don't know how, here's Dropbox's instructions: [What is the Public folder for?](https://www.dropbox.com/help/16/en)

Answer (score 0):

If the apk file is sent from a Gmail account to another Gmail account, the .txt extension will not be appended.